# authenticating with ember-simple-auth and torii custom authenticator

Tags: ember.js

I'm getting different behaviours from `session.isAuthenticated` depending on how I access it. This is probably only a symptom of my real problem.

What happens:

1. click sign in button
2. window pops up, prompts for login
3. login, popup goes away
4. templates that rely on
   `session.isAuthenticated` do not change display state (ie, continue
   acting as if it is false or undefined)
5. if I console.log
   `this.get('session.isAuthenticated')` I get `true`

When this was just torii everything was working, so I've messed up when adding ember-simple-auth somehow.

I get several `"DEPRECATION: Using the injected 'container' is deprecated. Please use the 'getOwner' helper instead to access the owner of this object` warnings but when it was just torii it worked fine with these warning so I assume they still aren't a problem.

**templates/application.hbs**

```
<header>
  <nav class="nav-main">
    {{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
      <button {{action 'invalidateSession'}}>Sign out</button>
    {{else}}
      <button {{action 'authenticate'}}>Sign in</button>
    {{/if}}

    Auth: {{session.isAuthenticated}}<br>
    <button {{action 'icanhaz'}}>test?</button>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**routes/application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
  actions: {
    authenticate() {
      this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:torii', 'myprovider');
    },
    invalidateSession() {
      this.get('session').invalidate();
    },
    icanhaz() {
      console.log(this.get('session.isAuthenticated'));
    }
  }
});
```

**adapters/application.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://myprovider.herokuapp.com',
  namespace: 'api/v2'
});
```

**authenticators/torii.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ToriiAuthenticator from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/torii';

export default ToriiAuthenticator.extend({
  torii: Ember.inject.service(),
})
```

**environment.js**

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'my-app-prefix',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    },
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
        'connect-src': "'self' myprovider.herokuapp.com",
    },
    torii: {
      providers: {
        'myprovider': {
          apiKey: '6T7hlTUqfYMgcxkXPAOeNzVmC5L26bTYe9A8D5fc',
          scope: 'read write',
          redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200'
        }
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject the session service's into all controllers/components that back templates you want to use the session in. As you're using the session in the `application` template you'd have to inject the session service in the `application` controller. Injecting it in the `application` **route** does not make it available in the template.